# Error on em.getTransaction().commit(); using the JPA @Embeddable annotation

Tags: jpa, embeddable

I have some problems with @Embeddable in JAVA JPA.
I have an entity class named "Author":

```
@Entity

    @Table(name = "author")
    @XmlRootElement
    @NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "Author.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM Author a"),
       ...})


    public class Author implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "aID")
        private Integer aID;
        @Column(name = "aName")
        private String aName;
        @Column(name = "aSurname")
        private String aSurname;
        @Column(name = "aPhone")
        private Integer aPhone;


        @Embedded 
        @AttributeOverrides({

         @AttributeOverride(name="city",column=@Column(name="Address")),
         @AttributeOverride(name="street",column=@Column(table="Address")),
         @AttributeOverride(name="number",column=@Column(table="Address"))
         }) private Address address;

    // set and get methods.
    }
```

Also I have an Embeddable class named "Address":

```
@Embeddable
    @Table(name = "Address")
    @XmlRootElement
    public class Address implements Serializable 
    {
       private static final long serialVersionUID=1L;
        @Column(name="city")
        private String city;
        @Column(name="street")
        private String street;
        @Column(name="number")
        private int number;

    // get and set methods.
}
```

In my main class I want to insert this values to the database. (I use mySQL) But I am getting an error on this line: em.getTransaction.commit();

```
    public class CreateAuthor extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "Project";
        private static EntityManagerFactory emf;

        public void CreateAuthor() {
            initComponents();
        }


        private void ekleButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
            EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();


            em.getTransaction().begin();


            Author author = new Author();
            author.setAID(3);
            author.setAName("Sheldon");
            author.setASurname("Smith");
            author.setAPhone(768987);
            Address adr = new Address();



             adr.setCity("Paris");
             adr.setStreet("cinar");
             adr.setNumber(12);
             author.setAddress(adr);



            em.persist(author);

            em.getTransaction().commit();  /// error occured

            em.close();       

    }
}
```

On my database side, I have Author table (aID(pk),aName,aSurname,aPhone)

Address Table (city,street,number)

Do you have any idea why an error is occured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal of Embeddable is to have fields of an object (Address) stored in the same table as the entity's table (Author -> author).

If you want to save them in another table, than Address should be an entity on its own, and there should be a OneToOne or ManyToOne association between Author and Address. The mapping, as is, don't make any sense.

Comment: what should I do to fix it? To create new fields for address information in author table ?

Comment: You should first decide what you want. Do you want the address to be stored in the same table, or in a different one? Both are possible. It's your choice.

Comment: I want to store them in the same table.

Comment: When I drop the following: 

@AttributeOverrides({       @AttributeOverride(name="city",column=@Column(name="Address")),
         @AttributeOverride(name="street",column=@Column(table="Address")),
         @AttributeOverride(name="number",column=@Column(table="Address"))
         })         
 and add columns to Author table, it starts to run. But why it is not working with override ?

Comment: You should first explain what is your desire outcomes with these overrides. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Actually,when you said there is two possibilities for embeddable, I tried both for learning all ways.First one, I delete AttributeOverrides and add address fields in the database Author table and it starts to run. 
Second one, I tried this with two tables. I added @SecondaryTable and AttributeOverrides to author.java(entity class) and created two tables on the database(author and address).It is running but when author information is inserted to author table,aID also inserted to address table. aID column in the Address table is full but the other columns are NULL(city,street,number).

Comment: Is there any way that author informations will be inserted in author table, but if I dont add any address information, aID won't be inserted to Address table. And other fields wil be not null?
 
note: I didnt use any connection @OneToOne, OneToMany,foreign key

Comment: I have no idea. SecondaryTable should generatlly be avoided. Use a OneToOne association if you want to store the address in another table.